# Fetching old token with RTK Query

Tags: rtk-query

I'm using RTK Query to get the user logged and put in my app, like showing user logged in header, etc. But, when i logged for first time, it shows only the old token, when i refresh the page, it shows the actual token and data.

My RTK Query archive looks like that:

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";

const useAuthToken = () => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
  return token ? `Bearer ${token}` : null;
};

export const usersApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "users",

  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: "http://127.0.0.1:8080",
    headers: {
      Authorization: useAuthToken(),
    },
  }),

  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getUserLogged: builder.query({
      query: () => "/check/token",
    }),
    }),
  }),
});

export const {
  useGetUserLoggedQuery,
} = usersApi;
```

and in other pages i get the info:

```
 const { data, error, isLoading } = useGetUserLoggedQuery();
  const [dataResults, setDataResults] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
      if (data) {
        setDataResults(data);
      } else if (isLoading) {
        console.log("loading");
      } else if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
  }, [data]);
```

and show to the user...

all works fine untill i logout and log in again, it shows the old data using the old token, but if i refresh the page, it works normally.

i know that it getting the old token in RTK QUERY fetching, but how i can deal with that everytime i logout?